# Display contact using foam - how is it working?

Tags: pcb, display

I was pretty stunned when I disassembled my Sonoff TH Elite by the way the display was connected to the PCB. Somehow the "foamy" piece is pressed onto the blank contact surfaces of the PCB and this works?

[image]
[image]

Can someone elaborate how this works or how this connection is named?

Thanks.

Comment: See [Elastomeric connector](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elastomeric_connector) on Wikipedia. I usually call them "zebra strip" or "LCD connection rubber", but to each their own.

Comment: It is using conductive rubber, see this: https://www.fujipoly.com/usa/resources/design-guidelines/design-guidelines-connectors.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *Can someone elaborate how this works or how this connection is named*

It's an elastomeric connector of the zebra strip type: -

[image]

Image from [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elastomeric_connector#/media/File:Zebra_connector.jpg). Notice the little individual carbon connecting strips separated by insulation. Close-up: -

[image]